# How can I remove Home/Folders from my Unity dash?

Tags: unity-dash

How can I remove from Dash the Home/Folders: 'Pictures', 'Music', 'Videos' and 'Downloads", which I have already removed from my `/home` directory?

Answer (score 2):

Edit / Remove them from  `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`, and `~/.gtk-bookmarks`.

Comment: I did it already. The folders are deleted from my /home but they are remaining in Dash.

Comment: I added another config file you could try, but I don't know if that's where the Dash is getting it.

Answer (score 0):

open **privacy** from **dash** and delete the history

[image]

Comment: I tried both 'privacy' and 'log activity manager' but the folders are still there (in Dash).

Comment: I tried also to give criteria results to 'search' excluding 'folders' so i cannot see those folders but anytime i log in the searching criteria are disabled and they return to default. Any idea to make the criteria permanent?

Comment: I tried myself it works

Comment: For me nothing of the above works.

Comment: try bleachbit, its a wiping tool but you must be careful with. there delete all cache and temporary files and etc... the uneeded files for you

Comment: As i am reading 'bleachbit' deletes unnecessary files etc. How can this program affect dash/files&folders search and specially the -deleted- folders shown there?

Comment: since you delete the user-dirs.dirs it means that you delete folders inside your home so there is no execuse to stay in dash unless they are temp files or cache or something like that so try bleachbit and test

Comment: I would try logging out and back in before trying bleachbit